# Is it safe for dogs to swim in chlorinated water?

Tags: dogs, poison, swimming

Owners of Labradors are probably familiar with their dogs jumping into everything that contains at least trace amounts of water, murky ponds, muddy puddles, etc.

An answer to [a question about a certain sort of amoeba](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1041/58) brought up the idea that it should be safest for the dog to only swim in chlorinated water. The answer has since been edited, but I still consider the question to be interesting.
Swimming in chlorinated water is safe for humans, as long as you don't swallow too much. I assume that this is also the case for dogs, but is hard to tell a dog not to swallow any water. Is it safe to let a dog swim in a chlorinated pool?

Comment: Anecdotally I can say that our pugs swim in chlorinated water (with their life vests) and have never shown any signs of distress other than the smell.

Answer (score 8):

This depends on the amount of chlorine in the water. From what I remember from chemistry class, chlorine is used to purify water so a chlorinated water, **if there is a chemical-balance** is not harmful to your dog. So it is important for the chlorine not to be too much.

However, if there is excess chlorine, your dog will fall sick, if he drinks the water. Even if he doesn't drink water he might get skin irritation and he might have eye problems if the water gets into his eyes.

**Make Sure the pH level is  between 7.2 and 7.5**

Comment: I second the skin irritation and eye problems thing, it's not just about drinking it, but certain breeds have much more sensitive skins than others, so I guess it's a matter of being careful overall and checking that a swim doesn't cause any harm and only get comfortable with the situation gradually.